Why won't data persist in a component that is reused?
I have a Vue component that is rendered on a route like this:
{
  path: '/chat/:Username(\\w+)?',
  name: 'ViewChat',
  component: Chat
}

The Chat.vue component should render at the path /chat and also /chat/michael for example.
However I lose my ref data when I go from /chat to /chat/michael which I don't understand why when the component is supposed to be reused.
This what I mean in Chat.vue component (code reduced for brevity):
<template>
<button @click="openMessages('michael')">Open messages</button>
  <div v-if="ShowMessages">
  <h1>Your messages</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
setup() {
const ShowMessages = ref();

  function openMessages(Username){
    await VueRouter.push({name: 'Chat', params:{Username: Username}});
    const SelectedUsername = Username; 
    ShowMessages.value = true; 
    
    console.log(ShowMessages.value) // Shows true but appears as undefined in Vue dev tools
    console.log(SelectedUsername) // Shows 'michael' which means the code ran after route change
}

return {
   ShowMessages,
   openMessages
}
}
</script>

The HTML to be rendered for ShowMessages being true doesn't work because Vue thinks it is undefined. It will only work if I remove the line:
await VueRouter.push({name: 'Chat', params:{Username: Username}});

Why would the code for setting the SelectedUsername and ShowMessage.value variables run but show as undefined in Vue devtools and so never work? The only way around it is to use a store but why should I use a store for simple variables in a reusable component?

The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown how you use router-view. What you describe would be possible if you used "key" to force the unmounting of view component. And it's not reproducible if you didn't do something like this

@EstusFlask You just worked it out. There was a :key=VueRoute.fullPath attribute in router-view. This was forcing a replacement of the component. That attribute has been there for more than year so I'm surprised it wasn't picked up on or caused any other issues

Glad it was that simple. This indicates that the comp has been written in too fragile way that relies on the lifecycle. Generally it would be something like updateStateFromParams(); onBeforeRouteUpdate(async () => { updateStateFromParams() } in setup, or just make ShowMessages a computed, route params are reactive
